# Solving a characteristics system

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> **Problem Sheet Question:**

A PDE initial value problem has three associated characteristics equations to solve $x,y,u$. The first, $y$, is a simple ODE and can be solved by integration with a constant.

The other two have the characteristics system as follows:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= u\\
\frac{du}{dt} &= x
\end{align*}

Where $x,u$ are both functions of the parametrised variables $s$ and $t$.

> **Solution:**
>
> Quoting from the mark scheme:
>
> "The above form a system which can be reduced to one equation by eliminating one of the functions. For example, if we eliminate $u$, we will have
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= x\\
> \end{align*}
>   Which can be integrated using the methods relevant to ODE's. Thus, the general solution is given by: 
>   $$\ x = C_{1}e^{t} + C_{2}e^{-t} , u= C_{1}e^{t} - C_{2}e^{-t}$$ 
>   Where $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are constants of integration."

**My Question:**

what is the method in full to obtain $x$ and $u$ using the solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think of it like this:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= u\\
\frac{du}{dt} &= x
\end{align*}

can be written as

\begin{align*}
x\frac{d}{dt} &= u\\
u\frac{d}{dt} &= x
\end{align*}

Substituting $u$ in both systems seperatly will give:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= u\\
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} &= x
\end{align*}

On rearranging we have:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} & - u= 0\\
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} & - x= 0
\end{align*}

Which should remind you of a general method for solving 2nd order homogeneous linear ODEs with constant coefficients. Hence we need to solve the quadratic characterisc equation:

$$m^2-1 = 0$$

Which has the roots:

$$m_{1,2}=1,-1$$

Since the roots are real and distinct we have for x:

$$x=C_1e^{M_1t}+C_2e^{M_2t}$$

Which gives you the solution your looking for $x$. However, i don't know why $u$ is negative, i could only find one solution.